# Batch com parâmetros no SqlPlus

Tags: oracle, windows, pl-sql, batch

Olá,

Estou precisando criar um arquivo batch que dropa o usuário do banco, recrie e importe a base com um backup já existente.

Eu já criei uma rotina que da um drop no usuário e recria com as permissões definidas, esta rotina eu guardei em um arquivo e para utilizar esta rotina, necessito informar dois parâmetros, o nome do usuário e se é para dropar ou manter caso este usuário exista, segue um exemplo:

```
SQL> @CriaUsuario
Indique o nome do usußrio.: <Nome_do_usuario>
Dropar usußrio? (s/n).: <sim para dropar e não para manter>
```

Já criei um batch, que conecta e chama a rotina descrita acima, porém não consigo passar os parâmetros para este. Segue batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

@ECHO OFF
CLS
SET usuario=<banco>
SET senha=<senha_do_banco>
SET sid=<sid>

SQLPLUS %usuario%/%senha%@%sid% @ImportaUsuario.sql "baseteste" "s"
```

Porém nada acontece, o sistema loga com o usuário informado, executa o arquivo @ImportaUsuario,  porém não informa os dois parâmetros. Segue resultado no cmd:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Ter Mar 13 17:47:55 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Conectado a:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Indique o nome do usußrio.:
```

Alguém sabe a forma correta de informar os parâmetros neste caso?

Comment: veja isto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18621153/4713574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar substituição por posição.
Por exemplo, o seu argumento "baseteste" seria referenciado por &1 dentro do script. Consequentemente seu argumento "s" seria &2 e assim por diante.

Comment: Funcionou lindamente cara....
Vlw